# Educate the Industry

Tags: simcity-4

Before I start asking, either I am really dumb or just missing something if the answer is completely obvious.

I have a good lot of industrial, an It's all Low-Tech. Every part of my city is well educated, except for industrial.

Can I educate the Industry and raise the tech level?

Comment: What version of simcity? 4? Societies?

Comment: @spund3 It's Simcity 4

Comment: Use more medium residencial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use community colleges to do that (http://simcity2013wiki.com/wiki/Community_College).

The tech level also raises without them, but really slow.

One or two are usually all you need.

Note: Be careful when raising factories level: if higher level factories start burning you will need hazmat to put out the fire (normal firefighters don't work). Since the hazmat are expensive I just let them burn then rebuild.